# iOS not getting accurate App version from iTunes

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

Actually Just want to implement functionality like if new version of the app is available on AppStore then end user will be notified for update the App.

There are so many answers on google but look at below my code.

```
func isUpdateAvailable(completion: @escaping (Bool?, Error?) -> Void) throws -> URLSessionDataTask {
        guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
            let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
            let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String,
            let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
                throw VersionError.invalidBundleInfo
        }
        print(currentVersion)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let error = error { throw error }
                guard let data = data else { throw VersionError.invalidResponse }
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any]
                 if let a = ((json?["results"] as? [Any])?.first) as? [String: Any] {
                print(a["version"] as? String ?? "")
            }
                guard let result = (json?["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let version = result["version"] as? String else {
                    throw VersionError.invalidResponse
                }
                completion(version != currentVersion, nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return task
    }
```

and calling this function

```
 _ = try? appDelegate.isUpdateAvailable { (update, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else if let update = update {
                if update {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Version Available", message: "New version of application is available please update now!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default, handler: { (actionOk) in

                        if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX"),
                            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
                        }
                    }))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem is that If new version of app is ready to sell and I open old version of app then popup will open and when I click on update button, It will redirect on AppStore. **But on AppStore rather then display "Update" button, it display "Open" button**

So I checked in my code.

When I run below URL manually on browser

```
http://itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?bundleId=com.mycompany.appname
```

Then download **.txt** file and got accurate App version But In my code `print(a["version"] as? String ?? "")` it returns wrong version number.

Where I'm going wrong? Please correct me.

> NOTE: I also used http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.mycompany.appname means removed country code from URL but not worked for me.

Comment: A bit lost here. You mean you redirect to the AppStore page after an update is detected, but it shows `Open` instead of `update` Or your problem is that you are not able to find that an update is available?

Comment: Update is found but It shows `Open` instead of `Update`. So I checked in my code. So what I found, By calling URL on browser I got .txt file and it has correct data but JSON object returns older version data.

Comment: Apple _always_ does progressive deployment of releases, for various reasons, one of them being geographic, another being servers load, etc. You can't trust that an anonymous request to `itunes.apple.com` is going to always match a user-specific response. Your best chance is to **DELAY** the notice arbitrarily... by giving it for instance 24 hours of time before telling user to visit App Store.

Answer (score 2):

This is headache issue for all iOS Developer to detect version of the App and notify to users for new update. BTW **@Cœur** and **@Alexis O** explained well so I don't think to explain more. Just follow my code.

By calling below URL you will be got .txt file

> http://itunes.apple.com/in/lookup?bundleId=com.mycompany.appname

In the file you also will find **currentVersionReleaseDate**, Use this data and time and compare with current date and time if it is grater then 24 hours? then you should display **popup** for update the App.

**Changed your code:**

```
if let a = ((json?["results"] as? [Any])?.first) as? [String: Any] {
                    print(a["version"] as? String ?? "")
                    let currentVersionDate = a["currentVersionReleaseDate"] as? String ?? ""
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
                    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

                    if let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: currentVersionDate) {
                        let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: myDate, to: Date()).hour ?? 0
                        if diff < 24 {
                            completion(false, nil)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Changed in *If statement* . Check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
   func isAppUpdateAvailable() throws -> Bool {
        let yourAppleID = "12454364536" //This is demo id, you can get your apple id for a specific app from the appinformation tab of itunesconnect account 
        guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
            let currentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
            let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=\(yourAppleID)") else {
                throw VersionError.invalidBundleInfo
        }
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any] else {
            throw VersionError.invalidResponse
        }
        if let result = (json["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let version = result["version"] as? String {
            print("version in app store", version,currentVersion);

            return version != currentVersion
        }
        throw VersionError.invalidResponse
    }
```

This is check for sending it on appstore: 
     //This is you appstore URL of respective app, you can direct put your appstore URL here

```
 let appStoreURl = "https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/AppName/idXXXXXXXXXX?ls=1&mt=8"
 if let url = URL(string: appStoreURl),
                                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
 }
```

Comment: can you pleas elaborate more about code ? What you did that will help me to display "update" button on AppStore ?

Comment: I thought you didn't understand my question please read it. I know how to redirect on App Store and all other funda. Question after redirecting on App Store why not display "Update" button instead of "Open" button?

Comment: Have you tried with this URL: https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/AppName/idXXXXXXXXXX?ls=1&mt=8 to ridirect to appstore so you will get update button

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. As Coeur said, Apple puts out the new update gradually and it won't be immediate. The update is usually finished after 24 hours.

Personally, I won't go with this approach. It's better to fetch the version from your server and you can update that value after 24 hours when the App is released. You'll have more control over it. Supposedly your new app is buggy. You have a choice of not prompting your user to update to that version.

Side tip:

- Make sure you only show the popup once.
- Don't show the popup if server version is lower. Another freedom to support "not" prompting the user to update.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still getting this problem, make sure you are doing these 3 steps:

- Your request cache policy should be : *.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData*

  urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
- Your link scheme should be **https**, not **http**
- Calling the **url** "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=(appID)" will get you the latest update after 24H. Update your link to "https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?bundleId=(appID)" to get instant updates. The path /us makes a difference, it's weird i know, but it works.

Note: For the third check, if you call the general link (without /us) from web navigator, it will gives you valid version. Calling it programmatically won't. That's why you need to add the /us path.

Comment: Yes, It worked correctly. 
`https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?bundleId=(appID)`

Answer (score 0):

My solution for delaying up-to-date version information of the app is...

```
class AppVersion {
    let major   :Int
    let middle  :Int
    let minor   :Int
    
    internal init(major: Int, middle: Int, minor: Int) {
        self.major = major
        self.middle = middle
        self.minor = minor
    }
    
    convenience init?(withString string:String) {
        let clearString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        var digitsArray = clearString.components(separatedBy: ".")
        AppVersion.appendDigitsIfRequired(data: &digitsArray)
        if digitsArray.count != 3 {return nil}
        guard let major = Int(digitsArray[0]), let middle = Int(digitsArray[1]), let minor = Int(digitsArray[2]) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(major: major, middle: middle, minor: minor)
    }
    
    private static func appendDigitsIfRequired(data: inout [String]) {
        if data.count >= 3 {return}
        if data.count == 1 {
            data.append("0")
            data.append("0")
        }
        if data.count == 2 {
            data.append("0")
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate static func isUpdateRequired(bundleVersion:AppVersion, appStoreVersion:AppVersion) -> Bool {
        if bundleVersion.major < appStoreVersion.major {
            return true
        }
        if bundleVersion.middle < appStoreVersion.middle {
            return true
        }
        if bundleVersion.minor < appStoreVersion.minor {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    guard let current = AppVersion(withString: currentVersion), let appStore = AppVersion(withString: version) else {
        return false
    }
    
    return AppVersion.isUpdateRequired(bundleVersion: current, appStoreVersion: appStore)
```